# Keras( with Tensorflow 2 backend) error while visualizing Layer outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using Keras with tensorflow 2.0 and I am classifying image using Mobilenetv2_.
The code for training and validation works fine. Now, i want to visualize activation of  certain layers.
Here is part of my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from tensorflow.keras import backend as k
k.backend.image_data_format=  'channels_last'  # for remote run
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,load_img,img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers,models
from keras.models import  model_from_json
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2,MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
#import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
from helper_func import save_batch_info,smooth_curve,save_model_hyperparam,save_plots,get_batch_stats
import tensorflow as tf
import os
# ********** SOME CODE HERE *************************
def Mobilenetv2_finetune_model():
    MobileNet_tuned = MobileNetV2(weights='C:\\ML\\mobilenet_v2_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_1.0_96_no_top.h5'
                                          , include_top=False,input_shape=(W_rz, H_rz, nc),alpha =1)
    #If alpha < 1.0, proportionally decreases the number of filters in each layer.
    # If alpha > 1.0, proportionally increases the number of filters in each layer.
    model = models.Sequential()        
    model.add(MobileNet_tuned)
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Dense(nclass, activation='softmax'))
    return model,MobileNet_tuned

model,conv_bs = Mobilenetv2_finetune_model()
#******************  Visualizing intermediate activations  ***************
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[0].layers[:17]]
activation_model = models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
img_pth =  'C://ML//test//52.png'
img_tst = img_to_array(load_img(img_pth, target_size=(96,96)))
activations = activation_model.predict(img_tst)
```

As I run this,I get error as below:
[image]

This is coming from line

```
activation_model = models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I followed Francois Chollet's book, and it was used similarly there.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
sedy

Comment: Looks like a subnetworking problem - see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767864/graph-disconnected-cannot-obtain-value-for-tensor-tensorconv2d-1-input0-sh). As a reference for future bugs, here's [code](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn/blob/master/see_rnn/inspect_gen.py#L15) working on all backends (TF 1&2, Eager, Graph, `keras`, `tf.keras`).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon : Can you elaborate a  bit please?

Comment: You should post _reproducible_ code; I should be able to copy-paste it and see the exact error you're seeing. Also, always add Python & TensorFlow tags to your Keras questions to increase visibility.